# Calculate the distance between two Centriods

Tags: python, image-processing, scipy, distance, deque

I'm trying to track a detected object in a binary video frames. Therefore I've stored the Centroids of the detected object(small red car) in a dequeue and used scypi spatial distance to calculate the distance between two successive centroids using the following code:

```
import scipy.spatial.distance
from collections import  deque

#defining the Centroid
centroids=deque(maxlen=40)
.
.
.
centroids.appendleft(center)
#center comes from detection process. e.g centroids=[(120,130), (125,132),...

Distance=scipy.spatial.distance.cdist(center[0],center[1)]
print('Distance ",Distance)
```

when i run the code, i get the following error:

```
 raise ValueError('XA must be a 2-dimensional array.')
 ValueError: XA must be a 2-dimensional array.
```

The error is logical,because the stored centroids are point vector of the the center of the car

**So my question is:**

How can i make this work in such a way so that i get the distance difference between every two successive Centroids?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`scipy.spatial.distance.cdist()` requires two 2-Dimensional array as input, but by providing it `center[0]` and `center[1]` you are giving it two 1-dimensional arrays.

If you want to feed elements of `centroids` one at a time, `scipy.spatial.distance` includes a function called [`euclidean`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.euclidean.html) which measures the distance between two 1-dimensional arrays.

To get the distances between every pair of sequential centroids in this way, you can just loop over the list of centroids like this:

```py
distances = []
for i in range(len(centroids) - 1):
    distances.append(euclidean(centroids[i], centroids[i+1]))
```